# Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error android studio 3.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-actionbar, android-studio-3.0

After updating android studio to version 3.0, I can't preview layout of my app, I get the error like:

```
'Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error'.
```

How can I fix this? but if I run the app on my device phone, its run normally.

This is my Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.halloo'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.+'
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.+'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.+'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:hfrecyclerview:1.0.0'
}
```

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: why have u put this "dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.+'
}" so many times????????

Comment: May i know why you have included `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.+'` this many times?

Comment: i think this is a bug in android studio

Comment: Sorry, edited my question.

Comment: @DheerajJoshi, any reference from google bug?

Comment: you can check here if it can  help https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Comment: and tell me if your problem is solved or not?

Comment: @DheerajJoshi of course sir, its stil building. :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158038/discussion-between-dheeraj-joshi-and-denny-kurniawan).

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51351324/8098918) will help you without changing library version

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to use the same version of `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, and `support library version`. I see that you want to use `buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'`. So, change all of them to version 26.

Second, you need to clean up your build.gradle. There is no need for duplicate dependencies.

Third, try clean and build your project. As the last resort, try `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart...`

Your **app** `build.gradle` should be something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
  buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.halloo'
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
  productFlavors {
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  })
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
  compile 'com.mikhaellopez:hfrecyclerview:1.0.0'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

You also need to check for your **project** `build.gradle`. It should contain `build:gradle:3.0.0` (as [@dheeraj-joshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8171929/dheeraj-joshi) has pointing out), something like this:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
//    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    google()
  }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Then, you need to check your gradle version. It should at least using `gradle-4.1`.

Comment: Hai, sir thanks for answer. thanks for annotation with compile, its help me a lot, but its still downloading for sdk 26. So, i have check as answer later sir.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem (maybe not exactly the same one).

I was able to run the starter code on the phone and the menu was there. However, preview pane in Android Studio didn't show actual layout.

I have fixed it by changing **Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar** to **Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar** in **styles.xml**.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in android support library version "26.0.0-beta2'

use:

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'`

with:

`buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'`
and

classpath

`'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha8'`

everything should work fine.