# Not getting preview layout in android studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

not getting preview layout in my android studio 3.0. I have attached screenshot of it with big arrow showing no preview

[image]

Comment: Please click on the red-circle close to the Gradle tab found on the top-right of the screen and read what it says

Comment: it says:- Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error.

Comment: Please check these three links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449275/failed-to-load-appcompat-actionbar-with-unknown-error-in-android-studio
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47067706/failed-to-load-appcompat-actionbar-with-unknown-error-android-studio-3-0 and 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50781913/failed-to-load-appcompat-actionbar-with-unknown-error

Comment: thanks for comment,i got the solution through answer by tanchap (one with 118 upvotes) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449275/failed-to-load-appcompat-actionbar-with-unknown-error-in-android-studio

Comment: congratulations :) Next time please make solid research on your questions before asking to avoid flagging of your questions or down voting, okay.

Comment: thanks,am new to stack overflow and android as well,thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***Please go through this***

```
1- Go to your res folder and inside res folder.
    2-Go to values.
    3-Go to style.xml
    4-change  <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    to <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

you have three solutions 
1 : clean the project and rebuild it.

2: if you are using target sdk 28 make it to 27 and change the implementaions to 27 and sync your project

3: close your project and reimport it